# Сохранение Excel файла сгенерированого NPOI в azure blob storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, azure

Подскажите как сохранить файл из NPOI напрямую в blob storage не сохраняя локально на сервер.

```
wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

// create sheet
sh = (XSSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
// 3 rows, 2 columns
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var r = sh.CreateRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        r.CreateCell(j);
    }
}

string connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxx;AccountKey=xxxRuoBA==");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.xlsx");

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.Write(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем не знаю на сколько красиво, но работает.
Ниже пример для генерации файла Excel c помощью NPOI и сохранение его как на локальный диск так и в azure blob storage

```
public class ExportToExcel
    {
        XSSFWorkbook wb;
        XSSFSheet sh;

        public void CreateXLSX()
        {

            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.

            string connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxTtyx5RuoBA==");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);


            //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            //    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.xlsx");


            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

                // create sheet
                sh = (XSSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

                //Количество заполняемых строк
                int countRow = 3;
                //Количество заполняемых столбцов
                int countColumn = 3;

                //Запускаем цыкл по строка
                for (int i = 0; i < countRow; i++)
                {
                    //Создаем строку
                    var currentRow = sh.CreateRow(i);

                    //Запускаем цикл по столбцам
                    for (int j = 0; j < countColumn; j++)
                    {
                        //в строке создаём ячеёку с указанием столбца
                        var currentCell = currentRow.CreateCell(j);
                        //в ячейку запишем информацию о текущем столбце и строке
                        currentCell.SetCellValue("Строка - " + (i + 1).ToString() + "Столбец - " + (j + 1).ToString());
                        //Выравним размер столбца по содержимому
                        sh.AutoSizeColumn(j);
                    }
                }

                // Сохранение файла на диск
                //using (var fs = new FileStream("C:/Users/Антон/Desktop/test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                //{
                //    wb.Write(fs);
                //}

                //Сохранение в Azure Blob Storage
                wb.Write(ms);
                using (var uploadStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()))
                {
                    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(uploadStream);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`XSSFWorkbook` закрывает/диспозит стрим после записи. Создавайте новый стрим на основе `ms.ToArray()`. Примерно так:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.Write(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (var uploadStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()))
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(uploadStream );
    }
}
```

Не проверял, но должно заработать. Похожий вопрос на enSO: [MemoryStrem seems be closed after NPOI workbook.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931582/memorystrem-seems-be-closed-after-npoi-workbook-write)